# Spark-shell not working in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, scala, apache-spark

Have set all the environment variables properly along with the spark package. The spark-shell as well as spark-submit is not yielding any result or error and rather going back to the prompt. Not sure on what config is missing.

Comment: Post more details with screen shots

Comment: issue was resolved the winutils version was causing the issue